# Can't install "org.Mm.eg.db" - zero exit status?

Tags: r, bioconductor

I want to install org.Mm.eg.db to convert a list of gene symbols to Entrez IDs.

`BiocManager::install("org.Mm.eg.db")`

gives me:

```
Installation path not writeable, unable to update packages: boot, foreign, KernSmooth, mgcv, nlme, survival
Warning message:
In install.packages(...) :
  installation of package ‘org.Hs.eg.db’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any ideas of what to do? Thanks!

Comment: Is this the only output after you try to run `BiocManager::install`?

Comment: "path not writeable" means you don't have permission to write on that directory. Check the OS permissions. And those packages are base packages, try to install without updating them.

Comment: Not being able to update the base packages is absolutely fine and shouldn't affect installation of the annotation package. I don't think that warning is of any consequence.

Comment: `Warning in file.create(to[okay]) :
  cannot create file '\uol.le.ac.uk/root/staff/home/s/saw44/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/00LOCK-org.Hs.eg.db/00new/org.Hs.eg.db/extdata/org.Hs.eg.sqlite', reason 'No such file or directory'
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Error in findpack(package, lib.loc) : 
  there is no package called 'org.Hs.eg.db'
Calls: <Anonymous> -> findpack
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'org.Hs.eg.db'
* removing '\\uol.le.ac.uk/root/staff/home/s/saw44/My Documents/R/win-library/3.6/org.Hs.eg.db'`

Comment: Could you add the *formatted, full* output to your question, rather than in a comment, please?